# Set PostgreSQL config from command line with ALTER SYSTEM

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-14

I need to write a shell/bash script that automatically changes some PostgreSQL configurations.

Here's the command that I wrote:

```bash
sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "
ALTER SYSTEM SET listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1';
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections = '200';
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_buffers = '24GB';
ALTER SYSTEM SET work_mem = '128MB';
...
"
```

However I get this error:

```
ERROR:  ALTER SYSTEM cannot run inside a transaction block
```

What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 8):

Use several `-c` options:

```bash
psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET param1 = 'val1'" \
     -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET param2 = 'val2'" \
     -c "SELECT pg_reload_conf()"
```

The final function call is required to activate the change.